# Apache htaccess rewriterule conflict between two urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My htaccess file is like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    'assign-associate-competencies'   assign_associate_competencies.php    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    'review-proposed-initiative'   proposed_initiative_review.php    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    'associate'   MemberAssociates.php    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule    'about-us'   aboutus.php    [QSA,L]
```

Problem is, when I try to open mysite.com/assign-associate-competencies it shows contents within MemberAssociates.php

How to modify it so that I can see contents in assign_associate_competencies.php?

Comment: Does `RewriteRule    '^associate'   MemberAssociates.php    [QSA,L]` function correctly?

Comment: @user3783243 works great. Thank you. Can you please add it as an answer, so that I can select it as correct answer.
I will need some additional help if possible.
In my site, users will signup. We want to create profile page for each user with their usernme, like 
mysite.com/user1
mysite.com/user2
etc. We don't know what the username will be so we cannot declare it directly in htaccess. Is there any way that it will automatically redirect like mysite.com/users.php?username=user1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more specific with your rule. Change `associate` so the match must be at the start of the request:

```
RewriteRule    '^associate'   MemberAssociates.php    [QSA,L]
```

For the user issue the common approach is to define a global local path, then pass the relative path to a parameter:

e.g. URL:

```
mysite.com/user/myusername1
```

then use:

```
RewriteRule    '^user/(.+)'   users.php?username=$1    [QSA,L]
```

to map that back to the users panel. Many sites do not use the text version of the user name, e.g. SO uses the value between the global path and the username `https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783243/user3783243`, `3783243` is used, not `user3783243` on all their looks ups. They also use a canonical look up to verify the user exists. Loading `https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783243/notuser3783243` throws a 301 and directs to the correct user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. We can always use mysite.com/user/myusername1
We are trying to figure out is we can do something like mysite.com/myusername1

For example, how facebook uses https://www.facebook.com/MyName to display profile of an user.